# Pandas Plot with Bar Returns Sorted by Counts?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I am using the following code to create a plot of how many nulls appear in my df, sorted by the date column:

```
df[df['Gas'].isnull()]['ReportDate_Time'].sort_values().value_counts().plot()
```

[image]

This is the plot it returns which is ok but I would rather use a bar plot. However, if I pass the 'bar' argument to the plot method, I automatically get my bars sorted by total count rather than sorted by ReportDate_Time, which is what I originally wanted:

```
df[df['Gas'].isnull()]['ReportDate_Time'].sort_values().value_counts().plot('bar')
```

[image]

How would I use the bars and sort by ReportDate_Time at the same time?

Comment: Using `value_counts()` after `sort_values()` essentially overrides the sorting. Make sure you sort your data as you wish before you call `plot`.

Comment: Hi there, its difficult to try without your data but...Have you tried to invert df[df['Gas'].isnull()]['ReportDate_Time'].value_counts().sort_values.plot('bar')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to sort your dataframe by report date, `sort_values('Reportdate')`

see below for an example.

```
dates = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-21'), pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01'),freq='D')
vals = np.random.randint(0,500,size=len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ReportDate' : dates, 'count' : vals})
df.sort_values('count',inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

---

```
print(df)
   ReportDate  count
0  2020-01-28    135
1  2020-01-30    194
2  2020-01-21    238
3  2020-01-29    316
4  2020-01-31    325
5  2020-01-26    408
6  2020-01-23    450
7  2020-01-22    451
8  2020-01-25    452
9  2020-01-24    454
10 2020-02-01    463
11 2020-01-27    489



df.set_index('ReportDate').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: bar plot]

and with a sort:

```
df.sort_values('ReportDate',ascending=True).set_index('ReportDate').plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]